# Creating a table from variable names

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to create a table from a variable name? For example I have the following stored procedure that I'm trying to write but it will not compile past with the create statement.

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'sabretooth'@'%' PROCEDURE `sp_archive_sabretooth`(
    IN vhost INTEGER(11),
    IN record_age DATETIME,
    IN delete_records BOOLEAN
)
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE i_exist BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE table_to_create, backup_table_name, database_name VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE backup_tables_cursor CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT DISTINCT (INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME)
                       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                      WHERE (INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'vhost%' 
                             OR
                             INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME = 'mid') 
                         AND INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'sabretooth%';
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;    

    INSERT INTO sabretooth.debug (message) VALUES (CONCAT('Initializing sp_archive_sabretooth; vhost = ', vhost, '; record age = ', record_age, '; delete_records = ', delete_records)); 

    SELECT INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA.SCHEMA_NAME
      INTO database_name
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
     WHERE INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA.SCHEMA_NAME LIKE 'sabretooth%'
       AND INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA.SCHEMA_NAME <> 'sabretooth_archive';

      OPEN backup_tables_cursor;

    create_tables_loop: LOOP
        FETCH backup_tables_cursor INTO table_to_create;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE create_tables_loop;
        END IF;
        CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS sabretooth_archive;

        SELECT CONCAT(database_name, '.', table_to_create,'_archive') INTO backup_table_name;

        INSERT INTO sabretooth.debug (message) VALUES (CONCAT('I am here 38 backup_table_name = ',backup_table_name));

        CREATE TABLE CONCAT('sabretooth_archive.',table_to_create) LIKE CONCAT(database_name,'.',table_to_create);
    END LOOP;
END
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is a concept called dynamic sql. To do this, you are going to have to use prepared statements. Lucky for you, [MySQL permits](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-program-restrictions.html) prepared statements in stored procedures, but not stored functions or triggers.

Also, lucky for you, [MySQL permits](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) prepared statements on `CREATE TABLE` commands.

So you are going to have to prepare the `CREATE TABLE` something like this:

```
SET @SQL = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ',CONCAT('sabretooth_archive.',table_to_create),' LIKE ',CONCAT(database_name,'.',table_to_create));

PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Look mom, no hands (or in this case, no Stored Procedure) +1 !!!

Comment: I think that the nested `CONCAT`s are not necessary and the statement can be simplified a lot. It should give the same result with `CONCAT('CREATE TABLE sabretooth_archive.',table_to_create,' LIKE ',database_name,'.',table_to_create)`.